# How to pass ruby variables to sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

How to pass variable from view to sass?

I need to override bootstrap `_variables.scss` depending on `request.host`
[It looks, that there is not simple solution for it.](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.FAQ.html#q-ruby-code)

Comment: Well yeah. It sounds like you're doing this backwards--what specifically are you trying to do? Sounds more like you want conditional classes/etc in the view layer.

Comment: You can't do that, your sass files get converted to plain css, that way you can use them in your views. It'll be better if you answers Dave's question so that we get the idea of what you're trying to do.